# Cascading dropdown with long texts(string)

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, spservices

I have a scenario where on selection of service, I am filling services description drop-down, which is working fine. But, since the description is having lengthy texts it looks really ugly. Is there any way the drop-down can be text-wrapped through code?

Note: I cannot reduce the descriptions string length.

Comment: No, default HTML does not let you. You have to simulate the whole dropdown control without using SELECT

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to change the width of drop down according to max lenth of description. [Resize Dropdown](http://www.aspnetify.com/2009/06/resizable-dropdownlist.html)

OR

You can show the title in Drop-down and add Tool-tip (long description) attribute to that item, when user will mouse hover description will be visible as tool-tip

```
ArrayList Items = new ArrayList();
    Items.Add("Short Str1");
    Items.Add("Extremely long...long...long REALLY long Str2");
    Items.Add("Short Str3");


    DropDownList1.DataSource = Items;
    DropDownList1.DataBind();


    foreach (ListItem LI in DropDownList1.Items)
        LI.Attributes.Add("Title", LI.Text);
```

OR

[GiantDropdown jQuery Plugin for Styling Large Select Lists](http://dpatrickcaldwell.blogspot.in/2011/06/giantdropdown-jquery-plugin-for-styling.html)